# Custom Directive and override another directive

Tags: angular

I am working on angular 6 and I have a problem with my directive.
What I tried to do is implement a directive that would be able to set the value of element's disable attribute.

For example I could have

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[permission]'
})
export class PermissionDirective implements OnInit {

 private userPermission: string[];

 @Input() permission: string[];

 constructor(
  private userServ: UserService,
  private element: ElementRef,
 ) { 

 }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.userPermission = this.userServ.getUserPermissions();
  this.updateView();
 }

 updateView() {
   this.element.nativeElement.disabled = this.checkPermission();
 }

 checkPermission() {
  return permission.every(elm => this.userPermission.includes(elm));
 }
}
```

And in the template I would have something like this in a simple case

```
<button [permission]="['permission1','permission2']">Confirm</button>
```

But unfortunately I have cases where I could have something like this already in the template :

```
<button [disabled]="form.controls.pwd.errors" [permission]="['permission1','permission2']">Confirm</button>
```

The problem here is that I would like my custom directive to have priority to set the disable attribute to false or true.
What is happening is that when the field become valid, when form.controls.pwd.errors become 'true' my custom directive 'permission' which set disable to false is useless here.

So do you have any idea on how I could do this, having a custom directive overriding the built-in directive provided by angular ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *export* the directive so that you can use it in the template directly. This has the advantage that you can write expressions and also use permission logic in the templates.

Here is an updated example, and I've removed the setting of the *disabled* attribute. You control how you want the disabled attribute set in the template.

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[permission]',
   exportAs: 'permission'
})
export class PermissionDirective implements OnInit {
   private userPermission: string[];
   @Input() permission: string[];

   constructor(private userServ: UserService) { }

   ngOnInit() {
       this.userPermission = this.userServ.getUserPermissions();
   }

   deny() {
       return this.permission.every(elm => this.userPermission.includes(elm));
   }
}
```

You can now bind the directive to a template variable as follows:

```
<button #perm="permission"
        [disabled]="perm.deny()"
        [permission]="['permission1','permission2']">Confirm</button>
```

Furthermore, you could bind attributes in your template to that template variable like this:

```
<button #perm="permission"
        [disabled]="perm.deny() || form.controls.pwd.errors" 
        [permission]="['permission1','permission2']">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as intended, I clearly miss the part with the 'exportAs' attribute